Tool for measuring filesystem efficiency on Linux
On different filesystems on Linux there are varying methods for storing additional data with creating, modifying (copying, moving) or deleting a file.
This information is stored in metadata specific files or disk sections (for example journals).
With measuring data throughput for a filesystem directory and monitoring disk I/O for a certain time this would show an efficiency range for a type of filesystem for a monitored computing system.
What tool can measure the filesystem efficiency for common Linux filesystem types?
What tool can measure data throughput for a filesystem directory for separately calculating efficiency in addition with a disk io monitoring tool (for example iotop or iostat)?
